# rearrange dataframe for paired items

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the a dataframe like this:

```
id           Shimmer
P01_S01_a    2.31
P01_S01_b    3.87
P01_S02_a    2.54
P01_S02_b    2.96
P02_S01_a    1.78
P02_S01_b    3.19
P02_S02_1    2.04
P02_S02_2    2.08
```

and I want to rearrange it to that:

```
id           Shimmer_a      Shimmer_b
P01_S01      2.31           3.87
P01_S02      2.54           2.96
P02_S01      1.78           3.19
P02_S02      2.04           2.08
```

I think it would be good to start with a range loop because it's always pairwise, but I dont know how to say python to rearrange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combination of str.split and pivot:

```
temp = df['id'].str.split('_')
df['id'],df['group'] = temp.str[:-1].str.join('_'), temp.str[-1]
df['group'].replace({'1':'a', '2':'b'}, inplace=True)

df = df.pivot(index='id', columns='group', values='Shimmer')
df.columns = ['Shimmer_a', 'Shimmer_b']

        Shimmer_a   Shimmer_b
id      
P01_S01 2.31    3.87
P01_S02 2.54    2.96
P02_S01 1.78    3.19
P02_S02 2.04    2.08
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with dictionary and `$` for last values of strings, here last `1, 2`, reshape by [`Series.str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) with `n=1` for spliting by last `_`, then [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and data cleaning by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) with [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df1 = (df.join(df['id'].replace({'1$':'a', '2$':'b'}, regex=True)
                     .str.rsplit('_', expand=True, n=1))
         .pivot(0,1,'Shimmer')
         .rename_axis(index='id', columns=None)
         .add_prefix('Shimmer_')
         .reset_index())
```

Solution with no `rename` last values after `_` but with counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df1 = (df.assign(a = df['id'].str.rsplit('_', n=1).str[0], 
                g = lambda x: x.groupby('a').cumcount())
         .pivot('a','g','Shimmer')
         .rename(columns=({0:'a', 1:'b'}))
         .rename_axis(index='id', columns=None)
         .add_prefix('Shimmer_')
         .reset_index()
        )
print (df1)
        id  Shimmer_a  Shimmer_b
0  P01_S01       2.31       3.87
1  P01_S02       2.54       2.96
2  P02_S01       1.78       3.19
3  P02_S02       2.04       2.08
```